# Using Selenium and BeautifulSoup Specific table is not returning by providing table ID Python3.7 ( returns Empty Array)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, dynamic-tables

I am trying to fetch a specific table from a webpage using BeautifulSoup4 and Selenium the table is present there but it is not fetching using this code.
I tried this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://de.sharkscope.com/#Find-Tournament/networks/PokerStars/tournaments/2412466083'
driver.get(url)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
targetTable = soup.findAll('table', {'id': 'tournamentgrid-1538318460041'})
print(targetTable)
```

[screenshot table With ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFJx7.png) 
and the Result
[DisplayResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL8O5.png)

**Platform and tools**

- Microsoft Windows 10 x64
- Using Chromium Webdriver ( installed version 32bit)

**Edited. I already Tried**

```
table = driver.get_element_by_id('tournamentgrid-1538318460041')
```

**&**

```
table = driver.get_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tournamentgrid-1538398792982"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing table using its xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_here')
```

or alternatively you can get all table rows(all `<tr>` element objects) by

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath_here')
```

and traverse through the list of row elements to extract required data, like using `.text` to extract text
visit 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html for more details

Comment: I tried using **find_element_by_id() ** and ** find_element_by_xpath()** never works at all